# How to write a C++ wrapper of managed C# dll having ref string as its parameter

Tags: c#, c++, clr

I am writing wrappers using C++/CLR. The managed C# class has a function signature as below

```
//C#
int WriteToInstrument(string command, ref string response, int stage);
```

I have to write a C++ wrapper to this function in something like the following signature

```
//C++
int WriteToInstrumentWrap(const char * command, char * response, int stage);
```

My question is: how can I handle the conversion from "ref string" in C# to char* in C++? Or how can I handle the situation that requires to take a ref string from C# that can be used in C/C++? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: C++/CLI is the weapon of choice to have C# code use a C++ class.  This is however a very different kettle of fish, reverse pinvoke can be quite tricky to get right.  Mostly because it gets to be very difficult to deal with exceptions.  The big problem with the C++ function signature is that you have no idea how big the *response* buffer is.  You have to know to safely copy the returned string into that buffer.  Add another parameter, say *responseBufferLength* and use strcpy_s().

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you. This is really important. The size can be obtained in the solution posted by "user9778277", and I will use that size for the strcpy_s.

Comment: That is not correct, there is no way to release a new buffer nor tell the C++ function about the different pointer.  The argument is not char**.  I suspect the user was not aware that this is a reverse pinvoke scenario.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes. I also found that it should be char**. Would you recommend to use std::string& instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add some examples of code I've written this morning. In general, when speaking of returning objects (in the broad meaning where even a `char*` string is an object), the big questions in C/C++ are:

- Who allocates the memory
- How many elements are needed
- How is the memory allocated (which allocator is used)
- And as a corollary, how the memory must be freed
- One last optional question is if the memory must be really freed: a method could return a pointer to an internal object that has a lifetime equal to the lifetime of the program and that mustn't be freed. For example:

  ```
  const char* Message()
  {
      return "OK";
  }
  ```

  You mustn't free the memory returned by `Message()`!

This questions get even more complex when you are writing a library (a dll) that will be used by other programs: the `malloc` and the `new` that are used in a dll can be different/distinct from the `malloc` and the `new` used by the main program (or by another dll), so that you shouldn't `free` with *your* (main program) free the memory that is `malloc`(ed) by a dll.

There are three possible solutions to this particular problem:

- Use a shared allocator, for example one given by the OS. Windows gives `LocalAlloc` and `CoTaskMemAlloc`. They are even accessible from .NET (`Marshal.AllocHGlobal` and `Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem`). In this way the main application can free the memory allocated by the dll
- The API of your dll has a `Free()` method that must be used to free the memory allocated by the dll
- The API of your dll has some methods like `SetAllocator(void *(*allocator)(size_t))` and `SetFree(void (*free)(void*))`, so methods that store a function pointer, that the main application can use to set the allocator and free to be used by the dll, so that they are shared between the main application and the dll. The dll will use those allocators. Note that `SetAllocator(malloc); SetFree(free)` if done by the main application is perfectly legal: now the dll will use the main application's `malloc`, and not the dll's `malloc`!
- Shortcut used in some example I'll give: the method has as a parameter the allocator (a function pointer) that will then be used

As an important sidenote: we are in 2018. It is at least 15 years that you should have forgotten of `char*` for strings in C for Windows. Use `wchar_t`. Always.

And finally some code :-)

Now... given (C# code):

```
int WriteToInstrument(string command, ref string response, int stage)
{
    response = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    return 0;
}
```

---

Simple method that calls `WriteToInstrument` and then copies the `response` result to an ansi string (`char*`). The buffer is allocated by the caller, and is of size `length`. After the method is executed, `length` contains the number of characters used (including the terminating `\0`). The `response` is always `\0` terminated. The problem here is that the `response` could get truncated and/or the caller could allocate a buffer too much big (that won't really protect it from the truncation problem, if it is unlucky :-) ). I'll repeat myself here: using `char*` for strings in 2018 is ancient technology.

```
// Utility method to copy a unicode string to a fixed size buffer
size_t Utf16ToAnsi(const wchar_t *wstr, char *str, size_t length)
{
    if (length == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // This whole piece of code can be moved to a method
    size_t length2 = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wstr, -1, str, (int)length, nullptr, nullptr);

    // WideCharToMultiByte will try to write up to *length characters, but
    // if the buffer is too much small, it will return 0, 
    // **and the tring won't be 0-terminated**

    if (length2 != 0)
    {
        return length2;
    }

    // Buffer too much small
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    {
        // We add a terminating 0
        str[length - 1] = 0;
        return length;
    }

    // Big bad error, shouldn't happen. Return 0 but terminate the string
    str[0] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Example of use:

```
char response[16];
size_t length = sizeof(response) / sizeof(char); // useless / sizeof(char) == / 1 by definition
WriteToInstrumentWrap1("cmd1", response, &length, 1);
std::cout << "fixed buffer char[]: " << response << ", used length: " << length << std::endl;
```

or (using `std::vector<>`/`std::array<>`)

```
//Alternative: std::array<char, 16> response;
std::vector<char> response(16);
size_t length = response.size();
WriteToInstrumentWrap1("cmd1", response.data(), &length, 1);
std::cout << "fixed buffer vector<char>: " << response.data() << ", used length: " << length << std::endl;
```

---

Simple method that calls `WriteToInstrument` and then copies the `response` result to an unicode string (`wchar_t*`). The buffer is allocated by the caller, and is of size `length`. After the method is executed, `length` contains the number of characters used (including the terminating `\0`). The `response` is always `\0` terminated.

```
// in input length is the size of response, in output the number of characters (not bytes!) written to response
// (INCLUDING THE \0!). The string is always correctly terminated.
int WriteToInstrumentWrap2(const wchar_t *command, wchar_t *response, size_t *length, int stage)
{
    auto str1 = gcnew String(command);
    String ^str2 = nullptr;
    int res = WriteToInstrument(str1, str2, 5);

    pin_ptr<const Char> ppchar = PtrToStringChars(str2);
    const wchar_t *pch = const_cast<wchar_t*>(ppchar);

    *length = (size_t)str2->Length < *length ? str2->Length : *length - 1;
    memcpy(response, pch, *length * sizeof(wchar_t));
    response[*length] = '\0';
    *length++;

    return res;
}
```

Example of use:

```
wchar_t response[16];
size_t length = sizeof(response) / sizeof(wchar_t);
WriteToInstrumentWrap2(L"cmd1", response, &length, 1);
std::wcout << L"fixed buffer wchar_t[]: " << response << L", used length: " << length << std::endl;
```

or (using `std::vector<>`/`std::array<char, 16>`)

```
//Alternative: std::array<wchar_t, 16> response;
std::vector<wchar_t> response(16);
size_t length = response.size();
WriteToInstrumentWrap2(L"cmd1", response.data(), &length, 1);
std::wcout << L"fixed buffer vector<wchar_t>: " << response.data() << ", used length: " << length << std::endl;
```

---

**All the next examples will use `char` instead of `wchar_t`. It is quite easy to convert them.  I'll repeat myself here: using `char*` for strings in 2018 is ancient technology. It is like using `ArrayList` instead of `List<>`**

---

Simple method that calls `WriteToInstrument`, allocates the `response` buffer using `CoTaskMemAlloc` and copies the result to an ansi string (`char*`). The caller must `CoTaskMemFree` the allocated memory. The `response` is always `\0` terminated.

```
// Memory allocated with CoTaskMemAlloc. Remember to CoTaskMemFree!
int WriteToInstrumentWrap3(const char *command, char **response, int stage)
{
    auto str1 = gcnew String(command);
    String ^str2 = nullptr;
    int res = WriteToInstrument(str1, str2, 5);

    pin_ptr<const Char> ppchar = PtrToStringChars(str2);
    const wchar_t *pch = const_cast<wchar_t*>(ppchar);

    // length includes the terminating \0
    size_t length = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pch, -1, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    *response = (char*)CoTaskMemAlloc(length * sizeof(char));
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pch, -1, *response, length, nullptr, nullptr);

    return res;
}
```

Example of use:

```
char *response;
WriteToInstrumentWrap3("cmd1", &response, 1);
std::cout << "CoTaskMemFree char: " << response << ", used length: " << strlen(response) + 1 << std::endl;
// Must free with CoTaskMemFree!
CoTaskMemFree(response);
```

---

Simple method that calls `WriteToInstrument`, allocates the `response` buffer using a "private" "library" allocator and copies the result to an ansi string (`char*`). The caller must use the library deallocator `MyLibraryFree` to free the allocated memory. The `response` is always `\0` terminated.

```
// Free method used by users of the library
void MyLibraryFree(void *p)
{
    free(p);
}

// The memory is allocated through a proprietary allocator of the library. Use MyLibraryFree() to free it.
int WriteToInstrumentWrap4(const char *command, char **response, int stage)
{
    auto str1 = gcnew String(command);
    String ^str2 = nullptr;
    int res = WriteToInstrument(str1, str2, 5);

    pin_ptr<const Char> ppchar = PtrToStringChars(str2);
    const wchar_t *pch = const_cast<wchar_t*>(ppchar);

    // length includes the terminating \0
    size_t length = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pch, -1, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    *response = (char*)malloc(length);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pch, -1, *response, length, nullptr, nullptr);

    return res;
}
```

Example of use:

```
char *response;
WriteToInstrumentWrap4("cmd1", &response, 1);
std::cout << "Simple MyLibraryFree char: " << response << ", used length: " << strlen(response) + 1 << std::endl;
// Must free with the MyLibraryFree() method
MyLibraryFree(response);
```

---

Simple method that calls `WriteToInstrument`, allocates the `response` buffer using a settable (through the `SetLibraryAllocator`/`SetLibraryFree` methods) allocator (there is a default that is used if no special allocator is selected) and copies the result to an ansi string (`char*`). The caller must use the library deallocator `LibraryFree` (that uses the allocator selected by `SetLibraryFree`) to free the allocated memory or if it has setted a different allocator, it can directly use that deallocator. The `response` is always `\0` terminated.

```
void *(*libraryAllocator)(size_t length) = malloc;
void (*libraryFree)(void *p) = free;

// Free method used by library
void SetLibraryAllocator(void *(*allocator)(size_t length))
{
    libraryAllocator = allocator;
}

// Free method used by library
void SetLibraryFree(void (*free)(void *p))
{
    libraryFree = free;
}

// Free method used by library
void LibraryFree(void *p)
{
    libraryFree(p);
}

// The memory is allocated through the allocator specified by SetLibraryAllocator (default the malloc of the dll)
// You can use LibraryFree to free it, or change the SetLibraryAllocator and the SetLibraryFree with an allocator
// of your choosing and then use your free.
int WriteToInstrumentWrap5(const char *command, char **response, int stage)
{
    auto str1 = gcnew String(command);
    String ^str2 = nullptr;
    int res = WriteToInstrument(str1, str2, 5);

    pin_ptr<const Char> ppchar = PtrToStringChars(str2);
    const wchar_t *pch = const_cast<wchar_t*>(ppchar);

    // length includes the terminating \0
    size_t length = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pch, -1, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    *response = (char*)libraryAllocator(length);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pch, -1, *response, length, nullptr, nullptr);

    return res;
}
```

Example of use:

```
void* MyLocalAlloc(size_t size)
{
    return LocalAlloc(0, size);
}

void MyLocalFree(void *p)
{
    LocalFree(p);
}
```

and then:

```
// Using the main program malloc/free
SetLibraryAllocator(malloc);
SetLibraryFree(free);
char *response;
WriteToInstrumentWrap5("cmd1", &response, 1);
std::cout << "SetLibraryAllocator(malloc) char: " << response << ", used length: " << strlen(response) + 1 << std::endl;
// Here I'm using the main program free, because the allocator has been set to malloc
free(response);
```

or

```
// Using the Windows LocalAlloc/LocalFree. Note that we need to use an intermediate method to call them because
// they have a different signature (stdcall instead of cdecl and an additional parameter for LocalAlloc)
SetLibraryAllocator(MyLocalAlloc);
SetLibraryFree(MyLocalFree);
char *response;
WriteToInstrumentWrap5("cmd1", &response, 1);
std::cout << "SetLibraryAllocator(LocalAlloc) char: " << response << ", used length: " << strlen(response) + 1 << std::endl;
// Here I'm using diretly the Windows API LocalFree
LocalFree(response);
```

---

More complex method that calls `WriteToInstrument` but has as a parameter an `allocator` that will be used to allocate the `response` buffer. There is an addition parameter `par` that will be passed to the `allocator`. The method then will copy the result as an ansi string (`char*`). The caller must free the memory using a specific deallocator based on the `allocator` used. The `response` is always `\0` terminated.

```
// allocator is a function that will be used for allocating the memory. par will be passed as a parameter to allocator(length, par)
// the length of allocator is in number of elements, *not in bytes!*
int WriteToInstrumentWrap6(const char *command, char **response, char *(*allocator)(size_t length, void *par), void *par, int stage)
{
    auto str1 = gcnew String(command);
    String ^str2 = nullptr;
    int res = WriteToInstrument(str1, str2, 5);

    pin_ptr<const Char> ppchar = PtrToStringChars(str2);
    const wchar_t *pch = const_cast<wchar_t*>(ppchar);

    // length includes the terminating \0
    size_t length = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pch, -1, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    *response = allocator(length, par);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pch, -1, *response, length, nullptr, nullptr);

    return res;
}
```

Examples of use (multiple allocator showed: `vector<>`, `malloc`, `new[]`, `unique_ptr<>`):

Note the use of the `par` parameter.

```
template<typename T>
T* vector_allocator(size_t length, void *par)
{
    std::vector<T> *pvector = static_cast<std::vector<T>*>(par);
    pvector->resize(length);
    return pvector->data();
}

template<typename T>
T* malloc_allocator(size_t length, void *par)
{
    return (T*)malloc(length * sizeof(T));
}

template<typename T>
T* new_allocator(size_t length, void *par)
{
    return new T[length];
}

template<typename T>
T* uniqueptr_allocator(size_t length, void *par)
{
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> *pp = static_cast<std::unique_ptr<T[]>*>(par);
    pp->reset(new T[length]);
    return pp->get();
}
```

and then (note the fact that sometimes one of the parameter passed to `WriteToInstrumentWrap6` is `useless` because we already have a pointer to the buffer):

```
{
    std::vector<char> response;
    char *useless;
    WriteToInstrumentWrap6("cmd1", &useless, vector_allocator<char>, &response, 1);
    std::cout << "vector char: " << response.data() << ", used length: " << response.size() << std::endl;
    // The memory is automatically freed by std::vector<>
}

{
    char *response;
    WriteToInstrumentWrap6("cmd1", &response, malloc_allocator<char>, nullptr, 1);
    std::cout << "malloc char: " << response << ", used length: " << strlen(response) + 1 << std::endl;
    // Must free with free
    free(response);
}

{
    char *response;
    WriteToInstrumentWrap6("cmd1", &response, new_allocator<char>, nullptr, 1);
    std::cout << "new[] char: " << response << ", used length: " << strlen(response) + 1 << std::endl;
    // Must free with delete[]
    delete[] response;
}

{
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> response;
    char *useless;
    WriteToInstrumentWrap6("cmd1", &useless, uniqueptr_allocator<char>, &response, 1);
    std::cout << "unique_ptr<> char: " << response.get() << ", used length: " << strlen(response.get()) + 1 << std::endl;
    // The memory is automatically freed by std::unique_ptr<>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a high level overflow, you need C++/CLI  (C++ that is using managed .NET code)

OK, you take a handle of type System::String (.NET) and get it's length property.  Use that value to allocate a new buffer of size + 2 chars using malloc and memset to zero it out.  lock the string, copy its contents and unlock it again.

There is a conversion operator to go from System::String ^ to MFC's CString, if that helps.  It will make the code a single liner

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. For example, if I use `System::String^ tempStr`,Is it correct to use `(char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(tempStr).ToPointer()` to do the copying to the unmanaged char*?

Comment: Also, be aware that the C++/CLI equivalent to "ref string response" is "String ^%response" (note the '%' symbol).

Comment: @Teller: No, that's not correct, it would have a memory leak.  Stay far away from the `StringToHGlobalAnsi` function and use C++/CLI `marshal_as` instead.

Comment: @BenVoigt, thanks very much. I changed to `context.marshal_as<const char*>(managedValues);`

Comment: @DaveDoknjas, yes, I used `String ^% response`, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  But again,

CString unmanaged = CString(System::String ^) does all that for you.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot.